# load dic err, can't open dicmap.bin （Python）

Tags: python

I want to run a python program on CentOS, and then this problem appeared. I even don't know the wrong place in my own code
[image]

Comment: the error message is：
load dic err, can't open dicmap.bin 
python: DicTree.cpp:735: bool analysis::DicTree::loadDic(const char*, const char*): Assertion `0' failed.
Aborted

Comment: What program are you running? Maybe show your source code.

Comment: Thanks，it's my first question,so maybe I didn't describe it clearly. Just one line code:  init('dicmap.bin')  in a function. And the file ‘dicmap.bin’ is in the same directory with the program file with problem.

Comment: maybe tell us which library or function you are using as well. Can't really tell by looking at the error message. The error message seems to indicate there is a library written in C++, and the library function is causing problems. Please take a look at [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)